# How big is the upgrade from phalcon 4 to phalcon 5?

Tags: phalcon

How is the upgrade from version 4 -> 5 compared to 3 -> 4?
Is it much bigger or same effort?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, for my projects, migrating from Phalcon 4 to Phalcon 5.0.0RC2 has been SIGNIFICANTLY smaller than any previous upgrade.  Of course I'm not using the full weight of Phalcon.  But the lift for two of my projects (out of four that I manage) has been less than one page of work and dealt mostly with changing some Phalcon names and such.  I posted a list of these in the Phalcon Discord general chat.